# LAST_PATH Redirection in Custom Login Post Action in Liferay 7

Tags: authentication, liferay, portlet, portal, liferay-7

I'm implementing custom login in Liferay 7 - one module for login hook portlet and one for ActionCommand.

I also generated class for post login event. The problem is redirection won't work on either this class or on JSP of login hook porlet.

This is my code for LifecycleAction:

```
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "key=login.events.post"
    },
    service = LifecycleAction.class
)
public class UserLoginPostAction implements LifecycleAction {

    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(UserLoginActionCommand.class);

    @Override
    public void processLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) throws ActionException {   

        HttpServletRequest request = lifecycleEvent.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = lifecycleEvent.getResponse();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        try {
            User currentUser = PortalUtil.getUser(request);
            LOGGER.info("USER|" + currentUser.getFirstName() + "|" + currentUser.getGroup().toString());
            LOGGER.info("LASTPATH|" + session.getAttribute("LAST_PATH"));
            LastPath lastPath = (LastPath) session.getAttribute("LAST_PATH");
            LOGGER.info(lastPath.getPath());
            session.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, lastPath);
            response.sendRedirect(lastPath.getPath());
        } catch (PortalException | IOException exception) {
            LOGGER.error(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code for porlet login JSP:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= themeDisplay.isSignedIn() %>">        
        <%
        response.sendRedirect(WebKeys.LAST_PATH);
        %>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
...
```

My LOGGER is able to display correct values on console.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The forwarding after login is a bit tricky.

If you use the LAST_PATH and session attributes you don't need the send redirect line because that will be handled by Liferay. The last path can be though affected by URL parameters as 'redirect'.

If you are going to use the send redirect approach. Build your URL and then past the URL that you created to the sendRedirect() call. Do not use the session parameter.

PS: If you are modifying the login have a look at the [AuthPipeline](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/authentication-pipelines) rather the doing heavy overrides to the login portlet.

Comment: As with redirect, my hidden input field has no value. I tried to manually put value for it and when I logged in, it successfully redirected to the page. I'm a bit confused as how it would get it value. Where does the parameter redirect get its value so that the hidden input for redirect would have the value?

Comment: As with LAST_PATH, if you can see my codes above, I set the WebKeys.LAST_PATH into session. I removed the sendRedirect. But, it won't either. Can you give me sample of login portlet/jsp and login post? Or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: I tried also to set the value of saveLastPath hidden input to true and removed/put back redirect input. It didn't work.

Comment: you should not have the redirect in both places. The action is the right place to address this. The hidden fields are populated by javascript out of the provided data and the data that are known. The redirect parameter is set by the source side so it will not be populated if you did not originate from an app that sets it.

Answer (score 0):

Post Login Hook via Page Redirection in Liferay DXP / 7+:

```
@Component(immediate = true, property = { "key=login.events.post" }, service = LifecycleAction.class)
public class CustomLoginAction implements LifecycleAction  {
private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(CustomLoginAction.class);

    @Reference
    private Portal _portal;
    
    @Override
    public void processLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) throws ActionException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = lifecycleEvent.getRequest();
        HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        LastPath lastPath = null;
        try {
            User user = _portal.getUser(request);
            String redirectPath = null;
            if(user.getEmailAddress().startsWith("test")) {
                redirectPath = "/group/guest/home";
            }else{
                redirectPath = "/group/guest/welcome";
            }
            lastPath = new LastPath("",redirectPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        if(Validator.isNotNull(lastPath)) {
            httpSession.setAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH, lastPath);
        }
    }
}
```