# how to access user screen name in liferay url?

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 7.3.2. I have want to redirect the user after login. I have created a public page and define following property in portal-ext.properties file.

```
default.landing.page.path=/web/${liferay:screenName}/login
```

How can I access the user screen name in a friendly URL while creating a public page?

I tried as follows but not working: **/liferay-screenname/login**

I want screen name in the URL because only authenticated users would access the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with these variables in properties, but a possible solution is to do this programmatically and write an OSGi `LifecycleAction` component for the `login.events.post` key. In your `processLifecycleEvent` operation, you can generate a path based on screenName of the logged-in user and set this as session LAST_PATH.

There are some stackoverlow topics about this, that might help here: [last-path-redirection-in-custom-login-post-action-in-liferay-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416572/last-path-redirection-in-custom-login-post-action-in-liferay-7)

Comment: indeed. I'm not aware that variables are available in the place mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that after login it redirects to the /web/username/login. But the problem in creating the public page, where we define the URL for the page. There I don't know how to define varial to access username or screen name.